# Python - Issue with batching and output number in csv's

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests

I am working on an api call which works but not exactly the way I want it to.  I added the `batch_idx` for loop to the code because I want to run the first 4 indicators through then write the results to a csv, then run the next 4 indicators through then write those to another csv, and so on until the `all_other_indicators` list has been exhausted.  The code below outputs several csv's but the first one has the first 4 like it should but the second csv contains the first 8 indicators instead of the desired second 4, and the third csv contains the first 12 indicators instead of the 3rd set of 4 and so on.  How can I tweak this code to satisfy my desired csv output.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://something.com/api/v2/intelligence/?username='
username = '<username>'
api_key = '<key>'
WAIT_SECONDS = 5

'''ALL OTHERS'''
all_other_indicators = 
pd.read_csv('Capture_Indicators_Months_Jan_Feb_2019/initial_all-other_indicators.csv')
all_other_indicators = all_other_indicators[0:20]
#all_other_list = all_other_indicators['value'].tolist()
column1 = list()
column2 = list()
column3 = list()
column4 = list()
column5 = list()

i=0
while i < len(all_other_list):
    try:
        for batch_idx in range(5): #how many time it breaks up the data(number of batches)
            current_anomali_indicators = all_other_indicators[batch_idx*4:(batch_idx+1)*4] #number in each batch
            all_other_list = current_anomali_indicators['value'].tolist()

            for row in all_other_list:
                value_api = url+username+'&api_key='+api_key+'&limit=10000&value='
                responses = requests.get(value_api+row, verify=False)
                data = json.loads(responses.text)
                valuess = data['objects']

                for index in valuess:
                    column1.append(index['value'])
                    column2.append(index['source'])
                    column3.append(index['trusted_circle_ids'])
                    column4.append(index['created_ts'])
                    column5.append(index['tags'])
                    all_other__output = pd.DataFrame({'Indicator': column1,'Source': column2,'Trusted Circle': column3,'Created': column4,'Tags': column5})
                    all_other__output.to_csv('Capture_Indicators_Months_Jan_Feb_2019/First_Seen_All_Others_Alone/all_other_with_others_first_seen_'+str(batch_idx)+'.csv', header=True, index=False)
        i += 1
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Time to sleep for 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(WAIT_SECONDS)
```

Current output:
first csv:

```
Indicator,Source,Trusted Circle,Created,Tags
193.215.253.92,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.252Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '0ze', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.231.105.253,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.299Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '32b', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
52.210.177.133,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.432Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'r5c', 'name': 'IP-used-by-simda-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.475Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'br3', 'name': 'IP-used-by-suppobox-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Blocklist Brute Force,[146],2015-01-31T01:16:17.770Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'name': 'Blocklist-Brute-Force-IPs', 'resource_uri': None}]"
```

current output second csv:

```
Indicator,Source,Trusted Circle,Created,Tags
193.215.253.92,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.252Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '0ze', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.231.105.253,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.299Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '32b', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
52.210.177.133,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.432Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'r5c', 'name': 'IP-used-by-simda-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.475Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'br3', 'name': 'IP-used-by-suppobox-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Blocklist Brute Force,[146],2015-01-31T01:16:17.770Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'name': 'Blocklist-Brute-Force-IPs', 'resource_uri': None}]"
88.77.192.110,Snort IP BlockList,[146],2019-01-01T08:53:30.643Z,
88.77.192.110,Talos Intelligence IP Blacklist,[146],2019-01-01T05:38:21.091Z,
88.77.192.110,Blutmagie TOR Nodes,,2019-01-01T00:28:26.492Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'v9t', 'name': 'tor', 'resource_uri': None}]"
88.77.192.110,TOR Exit Nodes,[146],2018-12-31T20:43:17.244Z,
195.88.242.31,Botscout BOT IPs,[146],2019-01-01T00:38:25.180Z,
http://hukum.ub.ac.id/Order/Document.zip,URLHaus ,[146],2019-01-22T11:18:30.065Z,
http://hukum.ub.ac.id/Order/Document.zip,URLHaus,,2019-01-01T00:58:59.597Z,"[{'id': '1q5', 'remote_api': True, 'org_id': '2316', 'name': 'URLHaus', 'resource_uri': None}]"
 http://easydown.workday360.cn/pubg/union_plugin_a2af16fdafe50c3f0faecce317c46e57_xzq.exe,URLHaus ,[146],2019-01-22T11:19:17.014Z,
```

Desired output:  first csv

```
193.215.253.92,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.252Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '0ze', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.231.105.253,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.299Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': '32b', 'name': 'IP-used-by-necurs-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
52.210.177.133,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.432Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'r5c', 'name': 'IP-used-by-simda-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Bambenek Consulting C&C IP Addresses,[146],2019-01-01T00:23:02.475Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'br3', 'name': 'IP-used-by-suppobox-C', 'resource_uri': None}]"
199.167.151.143,Blocklist Brute Force,[146],2015-01-31T01:16:17.770Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'name': 'Blocklist-Brute-Force-IPs', 'resource_uri': None}]"
```

second csv:

```
88.77.192.110,Snort IP BlockList,[146],2019-01-01T08:53:30.643Z,
88.77.192.110,Talos Intelligence IP Blacklist,[146],2019-01-01T05:38:21.091Z,
88.77.192.110,Blutmagie TOR Nodes,,2019-01-01T00:28:26.492Z,"[{'remote_api': True, 'id': 'v9t', 'name': 'tor', 'resource_uri': None}]"
88.77.192.110,TOR Exit Nodes,[146],2018-12-31T20:43:17.244Z,
195.88.242.31,Botscout BOT IPs,[146],2019-01-01T00:38:25.180Z,
http://hukum.ub.ac.id/Order/Document.zip,URLHaus ,[146],2019-01-22T11:18:30.065Z,
http://hukum.ub.ac.id/Order/Document.zip,URLHaus,,2019-01-01T00:58:59.597Z,"[{'id': '1q5', 'remote_api': True, 'org_id': '2316', 'name': 'URLHaus', 'resource_uri': None}]"
 http://easydown.workday360.cn/pubg/union_plugin_a2af16fdafe50c3f0faecce317c46e57_xzq.exe,URLHaus ,[146],2019-01-22T11:19:17.014Z,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define these column lists here (that hold the values), in the most outer scope:

```
column1 = list()
column2 = list()
column3 = list()
column4 = list()
column5 = list()
```

Later, you append the values to these lists,

```
                column1.append(index['value'])
                column2.append(index['source'])
                column3.append(index['trusted_circle_ids'])
                column4.append(index['created_ts'])
                column5.append(index['tags'])
```

When you handle the next batch, you have never emptied those lists (column1, etc.) and they still contain the old entries as well. You can fix it by moving the definition lines to just below the `all_other_list = current_anomali_indicators['value'].tolist()` line.